# Disable the submit button if the form is not validated

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**Functionality I want:** To enable the Submit button when there are no errors in any of the text fields.

**What I have tried:**

I tried calling validate() within the Form's onChanged() to listen for any error within the text fields to disable/enable the button. It works but the UI behavior is not ideal.

```
 Form(
     ...
      key: _formKey,
      onChanged: ()=> setState(()=> isButtonEnabled = _formKey.currentState.validate()
      child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
             
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.length < 3) {
                  return 'Invalid title'; //error with this message

                }
                return null; //no errors
              },
            
              onSaved: ... ,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter a price for your product';
             
                return null;
              },

              onSaved: ...
             ...
```

**Problem:** Calling validate() within onChanged() of form causes all the error messages of all the textfields(I have 5 textfields in total) to fire all at once. This is not what I want. I want to fire the error messages on user interaction only as I've set them:

> autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction

The only other way I know to enable/disable submit button is to set the isbuttonEnabled property within the

> validator:

of all the TextFields and within each and every if..else conditions. This achieves the desired UI behavior but this is very tedious.

Surely, there must be a better way to achieve this functionality?? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to do your 2nd solution enable the submit button from the validator ? It seems complicated as with autovalidate you cannot setState from this function. I'm looking for a solution to your problem its not that easy ;)

Comment: @Wapazz wow never thought of that. Doesn't work with autovalidation enabled, you're right. I tried to just set the buttons to enabled/disable in the validator() and call setState((){}) on the onChanged() of the form but still doesn't work as autovalidator calls validator() AFTER onChanged(). So the button is enabled/disabled 1 extra input later i.e if the validation condition was if(text.length>3) buttonEnabled = true... The button is only enabled when the text.length > 4. as onChanged runs before this validator and still has the previous value :/

Comment: Yes because if you check the order of the calls the validator is called last and then acts on the previous state

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class MyFormField with required String label, String error Text, ...you will have to write it once then call the widget with the parameters.

I tried this too: You can add specific key to your formtextfield (GlobalKey) and validate only this one through on changed. This option is nice ,...but , when I reset it validates because is a change . Maybe using other event works better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding a code example.